# Valid app Identifier Missing - Phone auth - react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

## [Error](https://i.imgur.com/TD1HbIz.png) I'm getting

> Console Warning Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error:
> [auth/missing-client-identifier]  This request is missing a valid app
> identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, SafetyNet checks,  and
> reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the
> logcat for more details.  NativeFirebaseError: Iauth/
> missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app
> identifier,  meaning that ***Play Integrity checks, SafetyNet checks,
> and reCAPTCHA checks*** were unsuccessful.  Please try again, or check
> the logcat for more details.

## Steps to reproduce

- npx react-native@latest init Example && cd Example
- cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
- // download the google-services.json with the sha1 & sha256 to the /android/app
- [Add these lines](https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-android-credentials)
- npm i @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/auth
- copy paste this [code](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth) into your App.tsx

## Stuff I did to get rid of the issue

- added implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0' to android/app/build.gradle
- Enabled API and Services
- Added SHA-1 and SHA-256 codes
- {PROJECT_ID}.firebase.app is allowlisted at firebase authentication settings.

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Comment: @Firate I gave up... Havent touched it in quite a while now.